# ChromeDriver cannot be found if using ordered Test

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, visual-studio-2015

I wrote a unit test using Selenium. The Unit test-class has a few (working) Unit tests. The constructor looks like this:

```
private IWebDriver _chrome;
public SeleniumTest()
  {
    _chrome = new ChromeDriver();
  }
```

When I run one of the UnitTests inside that Test class using the Test Exporer **everything works fine**.

But when I create an ordered test that contains the same unit test I receive an error when trying to initiate the ChromeDriver:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
       bei OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.FindDriverServiceExecutable(String executableName, Uri downloadUrl)
       bei OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
       bei OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
       bei OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor()
       bei MyTest.SeleniumTest..ctor() in C:\dev\myTest\SeleniumTest.cs:Zeile 27.
```

I added Selenium (and Chrome) using NuGet to that project

UPDATE: chromedriver.exe is inside the BIN-directory of the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that ordered Tests create their own directories and run the code from there. They look like this:

> C:\dev\myApp\MyTest\TestResults\MachineName 2016-06-15 15_26_39\Out

And inside this directory there is no chromedriver.exe

I solved this by using the `DeploymentItem` - Attribute. This attribute copies files from the bin-directory to the Out-directory before creating an instance of the class. So the class-Attributes looked like this:

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem("chromedriver.exe")]
```

After that the orderedTest runs without error

Comment: Now this works. And it can be used for other packages too. For instance, I'm using AutoIt to handle Windows-based logins (webpage logins not using only standard .htaccess), and adding the "AutoItX3.dll" as DeploymentItem does the trick. I do have to clean and rebuild the solution quite often, though.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the chromedriver executable. You should add the path to your chromedriver.exe in your PATH environment variable as it says in the execption message:

> The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

Comment: I know that. But why does this not happen when I run the Unit Test directly IN THE SAME project?

Comment: @OleAlbers I know too little about visual studio to have an answer for that.